# SVG Knockout text styling issue: unexplained cropped bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I've tried to build a react component for knockout text and I run into a styling issue I can't explain to myself.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4qw3lw6wz) is my attempt.

[image]

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundImage: "url(http://brokensquare.com/Code/assets/landscape.jpg)",
    padding: "20% 20%"
  },
  knockout: {
    borderRadius: 200,
    overflow: "hidden"
  }
};

const Knockout = ({ text, style }) => {
  const s = style || {};
  return (
    <div style={styles.knockout}>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 25">
        <rect
          fill={s.backgroundColor || "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"}
          x="0"
          y="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          mask="url(#knockout-text)"
        />
        <mask id="knockout-text">
          <rect fill="#fff" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
          <text y="70%" fill="#000" textAnchor="middle" x="50%">
            {text}
          </text>
        </mask>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = Radium(() => (
  <div>
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Knockout style={{}} text={"VERY INSPIRATION"} />
    </div>
  </div>
));
```

As you can see the bottom is cropped for some reason, instead of having the side completely rounded, drawing half a circle. Can anyone here see why and how I could fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Add `line-height: 0` to the div containing your `svg`

Comment: @RobertLongson Sure ! it's done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css, it will work

```
svg { 
   display: block
}
```

you can check below codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/71qxyx6m86

I added styles as below

```
render(
  <div>
    <App />
    <Style
      rules={{
        "*": {
          margin: 0,
          padding: 0,
          boxSizing: "border-box"
        },
        svg: {
          display: "block"
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

Comment: Works awesomely ! Thank you !